# How to allow users to change wrong email address in Firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are facing an issue in our app that uses Firebase auth. Some users register using a wrong email address (mainly typos in email address). The way Firebase allows users to change their email address is to send a link to old email address to prevent account hijacking. But in our case the old email address is an invalid one and the user wont be able to receive a verification link on. Is there a solution to that?

What we have in mind so far is to create a different flow using our own backend and using admin sdk to force email change. We feel this is not secure enough (again, account hijacking).

Comment: I don't think anything is built into Firebase for this scenario: if the existing email of the account is wrong or non-existing, the use can never receive the email to prove ownership of that email address.

Comment: I've got this issue with users and type-os in email addresses.  I was looking for a way to use the Firebase admin console to correct this, but it does not let you edit.  Looks like we'll need to add some sort of user migration to our application admin tools, and have them make a new account.

Answer (score 0):

using the Firebase Admin SDK you can change the email of any user. Also, you can set the new email as verified with the same call... something like this:

Node JS:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const auth = admin.auth();

const email = "new_email@provided_by_admin.com"

const emailVerified = true;

await auth.updateUser(userId, {
    email: email,
    emailVerified: emailVerified
});
```